# How to create hardlink of one file in different directories in linux

Tags: linux

suppose file name is file1 in home dir how can create their hard links on different directory
I tried :

```
ln -t file1 filehardlink > / home/dir2
```

Answer (score 4):

```
ln file1 /home/dir2/
```

This would create a hard link (i.e. an additional name) in `/home/dir2` for the file called  `file1` in the current directory.  The name of the file in `/home/dir2` will also be `file1`.

```
ln file1 /home/dir2/filehardlink
```

This would do the same as the above, but the new name of the file under `/home/dir2` would be `filehardlink`. Note that there is no reason to distinguish the two names of the file by saying that one is a hard link to the other. All names are hard links to files, and there is absolutely no difference between the names `file1` and `filehardlink` after the above operation.

This will require that the current directory and `/home/dir2` are residing on the same filesystem as hard links can't span filesystems.

Answer (score 1):

You can use command `ln` in such way:

```
ln /path/to/original_file /path2/to/linked_file
```

But be aware hardlinks by definition can exist only in same filesystem